# Quartic curve - what is the genus?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am studying the following quartic curve:

$f(x,y) = c_1x^2 + c_2x^4 +  c_3x^2y + c_4x^2y^2 + c_5y^2 + c_
6y^3 + c_7y^4$

where $c_i$ are constant (in fact they are expressions in terms of other
constants). Starting to learn a bit about curves, I found that a
necessary condition for a point $(x_0, y_0)$ be singular (a double
point) is that

$$F(x_0, y_0) = 0,\qquad
F_x (x_0, y_0) = 0,\qquad
F_y (x_0, y_0) = 0$$

and that the second derivatives calculated at that point are not all
equal to zero.
Solving these three equations (trial and error) I got two solutions:

$$(x_0, y_0) = (0,0),\qquad
(x_0, y_0) = (0, -2 c_5/c_6)$$

The second solution is a solution due to the fact that the
coefficients $c_i$ are interrelated. For both points the second
derivatives are not equal to zero.

Therefore, this curve has apparently has two double points, both with
multiplicity equal to 2. Thus, this curve would have genus = 1, if
there are no more singular points.

My questions are:

1. Is what I said above accurate?
2. Is there any simple way to test if there is more singular points?
3. If there are no more singular points, how can I parameterize a quartic curve
   like that? (I tried to transform this curve in an elliptic one, making
   $x^2 = z$, but I'm not sure if this is correct.)

Comment: If the curve is singular, there is more than one notion of genus for it.

Comment: In order to have an ordinary double point (= a node), you also need to have distinct tangents at the point, which means the Hessian matrix at that point is invertible.

Comment: I assume you mean the genus of the normalization of the curve. In that case there is a general formula for the genus due to Max Noether. In order to find the normalization of a curve, it is known that a finite sequence of blow-ups suffice (of course in your example, some tricks might speed up the computation).

Comment: In 3), you should not. This replaces your curve C by another one E such that C->E is a double cover. Now, you can use Hurwitz formular to compute the genus of C if you wish.

Comment: If indeed your curve has genus 1, because it has two simple double points as you claim (I have not checked that), then you can transform it into a smooth cubic in the following way. Take a quadratic Cremona transformation based on three points on the curve, two of them being the singular points. The result must be a smooth cubic.

Comment: Rodrigo, for the purposes of learning the subject, doing this
by hand as you are doing is the best approach. There are, however,
computer packages that can do these sorts of calculations. E.g.
take a look at the program *singluar* 
(http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/)
for example.

Comment: I think you should look also at the points "at infinity", by homogenizing your equation, to see if there are more singular points there, since this is an affine equation.

Comment: I don't think your second "singular" point is on the curve for general values of the coefficients. It looks like it's generically a curve of genus two. It is clearly elliptic if $c_2=0$.

Comment: Random choices of coefficients. Magma:
> A<x,y>:=AffineSpace(Rationals(),2);
> C:=Curve(A,3*x^4 + (3*y^2 + 7)*x^2 + (7*y^4 + 2*y^3 + 3*y^2));
> Genus(C);
2


Comment: In principle it is also possible  that the quartic is reducible. 

Answer (score 7):

This is not a real answer, since the curve you are interested in is not the generic one of the type you describe (you say that there are relations between the coefficients).
However, if you are starting to learn about  curves maybe you will be  interested in seeing how the generic such curve can be studied by hand.

The proper setting for the question, as pointed out in a  comment, is the projective plane $P^2$, so I'm going to add a variable $z$ and make everything homogeneous.  Also, since you say nothing about the coefficients, I will work over the complex numbers.

Consider the linear system  of plane quartics spanned by $z^2x^2$, $x^4$, $zx^2y$, $x^2y^2$, $z^2y^2$, $zy^3$  and $y^4$. The only base point of this system is the point $P=[1,0,0]$. It is easy to see that every curve of the system is singular at $P$ (it is true for all the generators) and that there is at least one curve (e.g. $z^2(x^2+y^2)=0$) that has an ordinary double point at $P$. Hence by Bertini's theorem the general curve of the system has an ordinary double point at $P$ and is smooth elsewhere. It is easy to show directly that such a curve cannot be reducible, so by the genus formula it has geometric genus 2.